# Generic class factory problem

Tags: c#, oop

Bellow is simplified version of the code I have:

```
public interface IControl<T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public class BoolControl : IControl<bool>
{
    public bool Value
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}

public class StringControl : IControl<string>
{
    public string Value
    {
        get { return ""; }
    }
}
public class ControlFactory
{
    public IControl GetControl(string controlType)
    {
        switch (controlType)
        {
            case "Bool":
                return new BoolControl();
            case "String":
                return new StringControl();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is in GetControl method of ControlFactory class.  Because it returns IControl and I have only IControl<T> that is a generic interface.  I cannot provide T because in Bool case it's going to bool and in String case it's going to be string.

Any idea what I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just derive `IControl<T>` from `IControl`.

```
public interface IControl<T> : IControl
{
    T Value { get; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If I missunterstood you, and you don't want a non-generic interface, you will have to make the method `GetControl()` generic, too.

```
public IControl<T> GetControl<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Boolean))
    {
        return new BoolControl(); // Will not compile.
    }
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(String))
    {
        return new StringControl(); // Will not compile.
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now you have the problem that the new controls cannot be implicitly casted to `IControl<T>` and you would have to make this explicit.

```
public IControl<T> GetControl<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Boolean))
    {
        return new (IControl<T>)BoolControl();
    }
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(String))
    {
        return (IControl<T>)new StringControl();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Changed the cast from `as IControl<T>` to `(IControl<T>)`. This is prefered because it will cause an exception if there is a bug while `as IControl<T>` silently returns `null`.

Answer (score 3):

```
public IControl<T> GetControl<T>()
{
    switch (typeof(T).Name)
    {
        case "Bool":
            return (IControl<T>) new BoolControl();
        case "String":
            return (IControl<T>) new StringControl();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Update; corrected a couple of errors in the code. Heres a call to get a class:

```
IControl<bool> boolControl = GetControl<bool>();
```

Comment: @Vadim - I would strongly advise you to use Daniel's solution, where he's comparing types rather than using strings. Using the name of the type is more error prone.

Comment: @Jon B: you are right; comparing the types will provide more robust code. I simply updated Vadim's original code to work. Daniel's approach is the better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The return type has to be generic, since, well, it is. Think of how you would use this. Returning a strongly typed object obviates the need for a generic factory method.

Even if you could do it, what's the gain of

```
IControl<bool> boolControl = controlFactory.GetControl("bool");
```

or, the one that would work,

```
IControl<bool> boolControl = controlFactory.GetControl<bool>("bool");
```

over a specific

```
IControl<bool> boolControl = controlFactory.GetBoolControl("bool");
```

Either way, you have the switch () at the client side. Either return an object, or have a non-typed IControl interface.